# Docker compose -f docker-compose-dev.yaml up fails without error using ecs context

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Im attempting to publish a docker compose file to Amazon ECS using the new docker compose up and an ecs context (using security tokens) however i'm getting a blank output in the console.

```
C:\Repos\Project>docker compose -f docker-compose-up.yaml up

C:\Repos\Project>docker compose ps

C:\Repos\Project>docker compose version
Docker Compose version dev

C:\Repos\Project>docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded

Logging in with your password grants your terminal complete access to your account.
For better security, log in with a limited-privilege personal access token. Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/access-tokens/
```

When i run the above against the default context it works as expected. Its just when im using the ecs context.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue? I have similar problems: `error="pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed" host=registry-1.docker.io` on executing `docker compose up` in an ecs context.

Comment: Yeah I solved it . I found a command that passed the aws token into the docker login command which got it working. I've got the command at home I'll post it later today.